# Browser intent-filter not functioning

Tags: java, android, browser

I am trying to have my activity launch anytime a user navigates to any website with a ".com" at the end. Here is my manifest:

```
    <activity
            android:name="com.example.myapp.BrowserIntent"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_browser_intent" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:pathPattern=".*\\.com"
                    android:scheme="http" />
            </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Anyone see what's wrong?